# Child component emits an event I didn't ask for in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm in the process of migrating my medium-sized app from Vue2 to Vue3.
I noticed that Vue3 Child-Parent emit mechanism is different compared to Vue2 and confuses me a lot.

Here's a basic example for demonstration

```js
// App.vue
<script>
import InputWrap from './InputWrap.vue';
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    InputWrap,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello world',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange() {
      console.log('why change?');
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <input-wrap v-model="msg" @change="onChange" />
</template>
```

```js
// InputWrap.vue
<script>
  import MyInput from './MyInput.vue';
  export default {
    name: 'InputWrap',
    components: {
      MyInput,
    },
    props: ['modelValue'],
    methods: {
      onUpdate(v) {
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', v);
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <my-input :modelValue="modelValue" @update:modelValue="onUpdate" />
</template>
```

```js
// MyInput.vue
<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyInput',
  props: {
    modelValue: String,
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(e) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', e.target.value);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
<input :value="modelValue" @input="onInput" />
</template>
```

[Link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) to Vue SFC playground.

I'm curious why does `onChange` event handler is called in `App.vue`?

It seems that `change` event is generated by input element in `MyInput.vue`. But it's totally not transparent why this event is going up through all components and being captured in `App.vue`. Imagine a tree with dozens nested components and a root component listening for `change` event. It's a total mess.

Vue2 have a different approach and I like it because it has a transparent child-parent communication. Is it possible to turn on Vue2 emit mechanism in Vue3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that Vue implements [Fallthrough Attributes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#fallthrough-attributes) mechanism

> A "fallthrough attribute" is an attribute or `v-on` event listener that is passed to a component, but is not explicitly declared in the receiving component's props or emits.
>
> When a component renders a single root element, fallthrough attributes will be automatically added to the root element's attributes

In your example, your component meets 2 conditions:

- `InputWrap.vue` render a single root element (`MyInput.vue` components)
- `InputWrap.vue` does not declare `onChange` as the component's emits

The same with `MyInput.vue` component

So the `@change` listener will fall through to the input element.

To disable fallthrough attributes you can declare the attributes as the `props/emits` of the child component or disable the whole feature for that component by adding `inheritAttrs: false`:

```html
// InputWrap.vue
<script>
  import MyInput from './MyInput.vue';
  export default {
    name: 'InputWrap',
    components: {
      MyInput,
    },
    inheritAttrs: false   
  }
</script>
```

[SFC link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

[Vue 2 only inherit attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs)

Comment: If I change first condition, I see the same result. For example, in MyInput.vue I can wrap input element with a div and still receive change events.

Comment: Actually, Vue2 behavior is different. To get the same effect as Vue3 emitter system, you'd have to add v-on="$listeners" attribute to EVERY component in the parent-child chain.

Comment: @EugeneKarataev When you wrap the input element with a div and still receive change events because the `change` event bubbles up to the DOM tree.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling

Comment: I was wrong about Vue 2 behavior. It just inherits attributes, not listeners

Comment: yeah, I'm good with DOM event system, but Vue3 event system still confuses me. Imagine I have a parent and a child, which has a lot of subchilds. I want to handle `change` event in the parent from the child, but I don't want to receive `change` events from subchilds. It seems that in Vue3 I have to name my custom events with more attention in order to not mess with DOM events.

Comment: @EugeneKarataev Actually, you can NOT normally ignore `change` events from sub-childs in the DOM system (not related to Vue at all). Because all events from sub-childs will bubble to the grandparent. You need to manually call `stopPropagation()` on each sub-childs to achieve it

Comment: Agree. Vue3 event system is close to DOM event system and differs a lot from Vue2. And it makes transition from Vue2 to Vue3 even more complicated than I expected. Thanks a lot for your help!